# Cómo limitar a un espacio por cada palabra?

Tags: javascript, regex

Quiero lograr, que teniendo un input, si al escribir más de un espacio, osea un espacio seguido de 1 o más espacios por ejemplo:

```
hola     como estas
```

Sólo puedo escribir 1, y para volver a escribir otro tenga que escribir cualquier caracter. He buscado pero solo he visto para java, python y .NET, esto intenté:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",f);
function f(){
 const e = document.getElementById("m");
 e.addEventListener("keyup", f => {
 var patron = /\s{1,}/i; // tambien intenté con: /?=\s/ig
 if(patron.test(e.value)) {
 console.log(14)
 f.preventDefault(); 
 return false; 
 }
 });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="m">
```

Me gustaría como se resuelve esto y explicado para entender.

Comment: A ver si entendi, quieres que solo se acepte 1 espacio entre palabras?

Comment: Sí einer, exactamente.

Comment: `/ {2}/` coincide con 2 espacios consecutivos, pero el evento keyup no se dispara en todos los casos. ¿Qué hay de celulares o cuando el usuario copia y pega texto?

Comment: Entonces, que debo realizar ?

Answer (score 2):

La solucion que daria seria verificando la ultima tecla escrita, si la ultima tecla es espacio tendriamos que denegar la escritura al segundo espacio con event.preventDefault();

> El siguiente ejemplo bloquea la escritura de 2 o mas espacios
>   seguidos.

como obtengo la ultima tecla escrita en el input? 
voy añadiendo en un string las teclas escritas y entonces obtengo asi:

```
teclaAnterior = teclaAnterior + " " + event.keyCode;
var arregloTA = teclaAnterior.split(" ");
arregloTA[arregloTA.length - 2]
```

aqui el ejemplo completo:

```js
document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("keydown", teclear);

var flag = false;
var teclaAnterior = "";

function teclear(event) {
  teclaAnterior = teclaAnterior + " " + event.keyCode;
  var arregloTA = teclaAnterior.split(" ");
  if (event.keyCode == 32 && arregloTA[arregloTA.length - 2] == 32) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text"></input>
```

Comment: ¿Y qué pasa si escribe un espacio, luego hace click en otro lugar del texto escrito y agrega otro espacio? ¿Y si copia y pega texto que incluye espacios consecutivos? ¿O si escribe desde un celular?

Comment: @Mariano en ese caso mi respuesta estaria a medias, pero no del todo fallida

Answer (score 2):

Para completar la respuesta de @x-rw, en base a lo que comenta @Mariano en sus comentarios, aporto mi granito de arena que creo que cubre todos los casos.

En realidad solo es necesario el evento `input`, pero hacemos una comprobación en el evento `keydown` para evitar la repetición de espacios cuando se deja presionado el botón de espacio. (Así evitamos que se dispare el evento input en este caso particular)

```js
const input = document.getElementById("m");

// Útil para cuando se presiona la tecla 
// espacio un período de tiempo
// Capturamos la repetición y evitamos 
// que se dispare el evento input
input.addEventListener("keydown", ev => {
  var code = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
  if(code == 32 && ev.repeat){
    //console.log('repeat');
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
});

// Evento input
input.addEventListener('input', ev => {
  var text = input.value;
  //console.log(text);
  input.value = text.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="m">
```

Con RxJS

```js
const input = document.getElementById("m");

const kd = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(input, 'keydown')
  .do(event => 
    (event.keyCode || event.which) == 32 &&
    event.repeat && 
    event.preventDefault()
  );
  
const inp = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(input, 'input')
  .pluck('target', 'value')
  .map(text => text.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' '))
  .do(value => input.value = value);
  
inp.subscribe();
kd.subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="m">
```

Comment: Exactamente. Algo así funciona y no es código antiguo que depende de una tecla... Detalle: vale aclarar que `\s` coincide con otros caracteres además de espacios, y sería `/ {2,}/g` estrictamente para espacios.